# Auto increment column value after 50 iterations

Tags: .net

As I am new to .net. I want to increment column value after 50 iteration as if record/rows exceeds 50 iterations then increment the value to 2, 100 then 3 and so on.

Here's the code I want it to be merged in.

```
sWriter_scroll.WriteLine("fix   consumer-no   scroll-counter   paycounter   no-of-total-paid   due-date   paid-date   paid-amount   paid-amount   fix  ");
        sWriter_scroll.WriteLine("");
        sWriter_scroll.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------");
        int counter = 1;
        
        

        for (int r = 0; r < dtc.Rows.Count; r++)
        {
                try
                {
                    sWriter_scroll.WriteLine(dtc.Rows[r]["fix"].ToString() + " " + dtc.Rows[r]["consno"].ToString() + " " + "scroll-counter" + " " + applyleadingzero(counter.ToString(), 6) + " " + dtc.Rows.Count.ToString() + " " + dtc.Rows[r]["duedate"].ToString().Substring(0, 2) + "-" + dtc.Rows[r]["duedate"].ToString().Substring(2, 2) + "-" + dtc.Rows[r]["duedate"].ToString().Substring(4, 4) + " " + dtc.Rows[r]["paymentdate"].ToString().Substring(0, 2) + "-" + dtc.Rows[r]["paymentdate"].ToString().Substring(2, 2) + "-" + dtc.Rows[r]["paymentdate"].ToString().Substring(4, 4) + " " + applyleadingzero(dtc.Rows[r]["paidamount"].ToString(), 9) + " " + applyleadingzero(dtc.Rows[r]["paidamount"].ToString(), 9) + " " + dtc.Rows[r]["fix2"].ToString() + " ");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
                rowCount++;
                counter++;
           
        }
```

Paycounter is working fine as it increments the number after every iteration so i want something in scroll-counter that will increment the number after 50 iterations.

i will be very thankful.

Comment: Could it be a single line like this? _counter = (dtc.Rows.Count / r) + 1;_

Comment: You mean you need to add code something like this into the loop? if (counter % 50 == 0) scrollCounter++

Comment: @Elliveny yes i want something like that. if record exceeds 50 rows then increment the value to 2 and next 50 then 3 and so on...

Comment: @Steve i have almost a record of 5000 on which i want to implement on scrollcounter column to increment number after 50 iteration default value will be 1 and after 50 iteration the counter should be 2 after next 50 should be 3 and so on..

Comment: Please try my comment or the one from @Elliveny You should get your number right.